# Have Humans ever gone to war against Gods or Entities before?

Tags: history

Was there a time back then when Humans would make a war against a God or an Entity? How did those wars turn out for the two side? Were humans strong enough to make that challenge?

Answer (score 4):

There are plenty of stories out there of Greek gods being fought and defeated!

> In Greek mythology, gods were often fought by both other gods and mortals. The mortal Arachne soundly defeated Athena
>
> the demigod Heracles killed a number of Poseidon’s sons
>
> Hades kidnapped the god Persephone to become his wife
>
> the great mortal hero Diomedes injured Aphrodite and Aeneas in battle, etc.

In Jewish theology, Yahweh is supposed to be perfect and undefeatable. Despite this, there are definitely ways you can beat the Jewish God.

> When Satan made a bet with Yahweh that Job would turn away from Him, it was completely possible that Job could have failed the test after having his family and slaves murdered. Free will is supposed to be a very important thing to Yahweh, and as such, Job indubitably could have turned away from God.
> Why would Satan make a bet with God if he knew that God knew the answer? The bet would have never been made if Job’s fate was already sealed… Satan is described as being too clever to do something so stupid. Job could’ve cursed God, and Satan would have won the fight.
>
> Moses also defeated Yahweh in an intellectual battle. Exodus 32 describes how God wanted to kill all of the Israelites after Aaron made them dance naked around the golden calf. Moses instead reasoned with God and told him to “turn from thy fierce wrath, and repent of this evil against thy people.” God, seeing the wisdom of Moses, changed His mind, thus admitting that Moses’s idea is better than His own. Moses defeated God in a battle of ideas. “…And the Lord repented of the evil which he thought to do unto his people.” Nice job, Moses!

https://www.quora.com/Can-you-fight-God-and-win-Is-it-possible

Comment: Note that standard Jewish theology does not consider Satan or Moses as having "defeated" God, despite the Scriptural implications.

Answer (score 2):

In the Indian [Vedas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedas) there is handsome history about that. It is described in [Bhagavad-Gita](http://bhagavad-gita.org/).

> The Bhagavad-Gita is considered by eastern and western scholars alike to be among the greatest spiritual books the world has ever known. In a very clear and wonderful way the Supreme Lord Krishna describes the science of self-realization and the exact process by which a human being can establish their eternal relationship with God.

The action takes place on the battlefield where [Krishna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krishna) himself is part of that battle.

---

**Caution:** Don't be confused with **Bhagavad-gita As It Is**

Comment: Your quotation doesn't appear to be more than a general statement about to the Bhagavad-Gita. It doesn't pertain to the question, which is about mortals going to war against gods. Could you please edit in a more pertinent quote describing the "action" you allude to?

Answer (score 1):

The Irish pseudo-histories forming the various Leabrad Gabála Érenn ("The Books of the Taking of Ireland"), place the arrival of what are thought to be a later development on pre-Christian deities, the Tuatha Dé ("The God Tribes") before the historical inhabitants of Ireland the Gaels. This necessarily involves antagonistic relationships, outright conflict, and peace treaties.

> §70. [The first night afterwards [when] Íth went into Ireland after Ins arrival at Loch Sailech], demons slew one of his followers. He is the first who was slain in Ireland there, of the progeny of the Sons of Míl.
>
> ...
>
> So it was to avenge Íth that the sons of Míl [to wit, the Gáedil] came--for his [Íth's] body was carried to Spain.

*The 'cause' for the Gaels to come to Ireland.*

> §76. The Sons of Míl fought the battle of Life; there were monsters in shapes of giants which the Túatha Dé Danann had summoned to themselves by druidry. The Sons of Míl (Éber, Érimón and Ír), fought the battle valiantly. The horse (gabar) of Érimón fell there, unde Gabar Life rwminatur. They came thereafter till they were in the mountain over against [Loch] Dergderc.

*The battle of Life against the Túatha Dé Danann.*

> §79. They had colloquy with Ériu in Uisnech. She said unto them: Warriors, said she, welcome to you. Long have soothsayers had [knowledge of] your coming. Yours shall be this island for ever; and to the east of the world there shall not be a better island. No race shall there be, more numerous than yours. Good is that, said Amorgen; good is the prophecy. Not right were it to thank her, said Éber Donn, eldest of the sons of Míl; thank our gods and our own might.

*Éber Donn antagonises Ériu.*

> There was a wondrous king over the Tuatha Dé in Ireland, Dagán by name. Great was his power, even over the sons of Mil after they had seized the land. For the Tuatha Dé; blighted the grain and the milk of the sons of Mil until they made a treaty with the Dagda. Thereafter they preserved their grain and their milk for them.

*A peace treaty of sorts*

**Sources:**

1. [Lebor Gabala Erenn (LL Edition)](http://www.maryjones.us/ctexts/leborgabala.html)
2. [The Taking of the Sid (LL Edition)](http://sejh.pagesperso-orange.fr/keltia/version-en/taking-sid.html)

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly **Vespersian**, the Roman emperor, led hundreds of soldiers into the sea to fight Neptune

Comment: Hi. I'm glad you want to participate,  but you're going to have to be a little more diligent in your future posts. The [help center](http://mythology.stackexchange.com/help) has a lot of good advice on how to ask questions and post answers.  Pretty much everyone here has learned the hard way to think about what we're going to write, and do research, before we start typing. We do this even if we're sure we have the correct answer, not only because we have to convince readers, but also because some detail we missed gives us an unpleasant surprise,